# Parse radio button responses into array (Express.js)

Tags: html, node.js, express

I've got a series of radio button groups set up, to represent answers to questions.

In the format of:

What Is your favourite Colour
Red | Blue

Markup:

```
<input type="radio" name="Question_1" value="Red" id="Question_1_Red" /> 
<label for="Question_1_Red">Red</label>

<input type="radio" name="Question_1" value="Blue" id="Question_1_Blue" /> 
<label for="Question_1_Blue">Blue</label>
```

I'm using node (express)

In req.body, I'm getting back the following:

Question_1: 'Red',
Question_2: 'Other Answer',
Question_3: 'Another Answer'

My question is, how can I put this into an array, so I can store it like:

[{questionID: 1, answer: "Red"},
{questionID: 2, answer: "Other Answer"}]

Answer (score 1):

```
var newBody = [];
for (var k in req.body) {
  var m = k.match(/^Question_(\d)$/);
  if (m) {
    newBody.push({questionID: m[1], answer: req.body[k]});
  }
}
```